# Pandas iterate over rows and remove string value in one column from another

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe (`carsML`) that looks something like this:

```
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
| carManufacturer | carModel |   carType    |
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
| VW              | POLO     | 1.4 TDI      |
| VW              | POLO     | POLO 1.4 TDI |
| VW              | POLO     | 1.6 TDI      |
| VW              | POLO     | 1.4          |
| VW              | POLO     | POLO 1.6 TDI |
|+-----------------+----------+--------------+
```

I want to iterate over rows, check weather `carModel` is contained in `carType` and if it is than remove it. So instead of having POLO 1.4 TDI it should be just 1.4 TDI.

One constraint - some `carModels` can be single letter long (like just `1` or `A`). In that case skip replacement and do nothing. Script should work only for `carModels` that are `len(carModel)>1`

So far I have:

```
for row in carsML.itertuples():
    if len(row.carModel) > 1:
        carsML.iloc[row.Index].carType = row.carType.replace(row.carModel,"")
```

But this doesn't changes anything..I don't know why..

Comment: You should include the example of `carModel`  with length `1` as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you well, the following one-liner could do your job:

```
carsML.carType = carsML.apply(lambda row: row.carType.strip(row.carModel) if len(row.carModel) > 1 else row.carType, axis=1)
```

Comment: That's nice but it's not covering condition that len(carModel)>1

Comment: @Harvey, I am sorry, I have just edited my answer. Now, it should be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll use your answer since it's much faster. +1 for all good answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.Series.replace` with `where`:

```
# Extra row with single letter carModel:
  carManufacturer carModel       carType
0              VW     POLO       1.4 TDI
1              VW     POLO  POLO 1.4 TDI
2              VW     POLO       1.6 TDI
3              VW     POLO           1.4
4              VW     POLO  POLO 1.6 TDI
5              VW        P  POLO 1.6 TDI

df['carType'] = df['carType'].where(~df['carModel'].str.len().gt(1), 
                                    df['carType'].replace(df['carModel'], "", regex=True)).str.strip()
```

Output:

```
  carManufacturer carModel       carType
0              VW     POLO       1.4 TDI
1              VW     POLO       1.4 TDI
2              VW     POLO       1.6 TDI
3              VW     POLO           1.4
4              VW     POLO       1.6 TDI
5              VW        P  POLO 1.6 TDI
```

Comment: It's working, how come I cannot use regex=True in my expression? it's giving me error. And in your case it's working.

Answer (score 1):

How did you declared your dataFrame?
I done the test:

```
>>> raw_data = {
...   'carManufacturer': ['VW','VW','VW','VW','VW'],
...   'carModel': ['POLO','POLO','POLO','POLO','POLO'],
...   'carType': ['1.4 TDI', 'POLO 1.4 TDI', '1.6 TDI', '1.4', 'POLO 1.6 TDI']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=["carManufacturer", "carModel", "carType"])
>>> df
  carManufacturer carModel       carType
0              VW     POLO       1.4 TDI
1              VW     POLO  POLO 1.4 TDI
2              VW     POLO       1.6 TDI
3              VW     POLO           1.4
4              VW     POLO  POLO 1.6 TDI
```

after I done:

```
>>> for row in df.itertuples():
...   if len(row.carModel) > 1:
...      df.iloc[row.Index].carType = row.carType.replace(row.carModel,"")
...
>>> df
```

And that is the result:

```
>>> df
  carManufacturer carModel   carType
0              VW     POLO   1.4 TDI
1              VW     POLO   1.4 TDI
2              VW     POLO   1.6 TDI
3              VW     POLO       1.4
4              VW     POLO   1.6 TDI
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: I guess my testing was wrong and my code is ok. Thank you!